# Can I get 2 AA to provide 4+ amp pulses at 5V?

Tags: power-supply, batteries, switching-regulator

I can find plenty of circuits that can boost 1-3V to 5V at low 200mA ranges, but nothing that would allow for a powerful burst, like IR remote at high power, needing 30-50ms pulses of 4A at 5V, then back to idling at 100mA or less...

What is the minimum number of AA battery possible to achieve this?

Any existing IC from any manufacturer, or is it a custom circuit design?

I currently use Li-Ion, but want to make removable disposable battery and light weight.

Comment: Sounds to me like what you need is *mostly* a really big capacitor...

Comment: what duty cycle are we looking at here?

Comment: Boost converter or change pump connected to Supercap(s)! I'd give you a link, but silly Stack Exchange zealots would likely delete this comment, so you will have to waste time googling for yourself.

Comment: about a 10% duty cycle max, 2.5% average per 1000ms (maybe 30ms x 5 x 0.5 for on time per 1000ms)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [LT3750 Capacitor Charger Controller](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/lt-journal/LTMag-V16N01-06-LT3750-Ng.pdf) .  It runs down to 3V, so it would be marginal with 2 alkaline cells, but would certainly run with 3 cells.  Put a high current low dropout regulator like the [Microchip MIC29501](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/MIC29501)  on the charged capacitor at the output.  Charge the capacitor up to 6V, turn on the LDO to drive 5V to the output at up to 5A.  You would need something that set the enable pin on the LDO for the desired pulse time.  Between activations, once the capacitor is charged, the current draw would be very small.  Note that you probably want a constant current to drive the IR LED instead of a constant voltage, but that is beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: yes, I would probably just drop a resistor in series with LED, and try to give it close to 5V to GND through the drain of NMOS when modulated.