# How to fast charge capacitor 2200uF/400v in fewer seconds?

Tags: capacitor, transformer, converter, charge

[image]I have a problem to charge a capacitor 2200uF/400v. It takes 30 second to reach 300v. I hope can reach 300v in 10 seconds. thanks :)

This my schematic:
[![the capacitor its on output (cn2)
 i use transformer toroid inner diameter = 5cm, outside diameter = 8cm, high = 3cm , for secondary 350 turn (0.7mm) for primary 14 turn (1.8mm)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2ewJ.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2ewJ.png)

Comment: Would the answer to this question help? https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/356437/can-i-get-2-aa-to-provide-4-amp-pulses-at-5v/356446#356446

Comment: [The elements on this picture are too small...](https://forum.bodybuilding.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=8564241&d=1486661977) Even clicking on the image doesn't resize it and thus makes it really hard to read. This is why we encourage people to utilize our schematic editor on this website so we can interact with it and zoom in if necessary.

Comment: I have difficulty understanding, i am newbie @crj11

Comment: Did you look at the LTC3750 app not that was linked?  It explains how the chip works and gives some good application tips.  LTC also makes an eval board for the chip: http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/demo-board-manual/dc891A.pdf

Comment: Here is another app note http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/design-note/dn405f.pdf for the part.  There is even an LTSpice demo schematic: http://www.linear.com/docs/16858 .  LTSpice is a wonderful free schematic entry and spice simulator program

Comment: oke tahnks :) but that stuff is dificult to find in my country

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you want to ramp up the voltage at 30 volts per second so that (with a bit of hand waving) you attain 300 volts in about 10 seconds. Now Q = CV and dQ/dt (aka current) = C dv/dt so plug the numbers in and the current needed to charge the capacitor is 2200 uF x 30 V/s = 66 mA.

You have a step up transformer with a ratio of 185/14: -

[image]

So, the input current to the primary will be about 0.9 amps. Doesn't sound too bad with a bit of hand-waving. It might need as much as 1.5 amps if I did a really good analysis and took into account switching losses etc..

So maybe your power supply isn't robust enough for the task - have you checked to see if the supply collapses during the charging period? Maybe your power rail is too low and the IRFZ44 (?) MOSFETs are not being driven hard enough?

Comment: thanks for your respon, maybe you like to take look my edit. I have been researching this for 2 months and many problems that I am facing.. thanks :)

Comment: What power supply are you using to provide power to the circuit?

Comment: lithium battery 5500mAh 12v @Andy aka

Comment: What about a link to the actual part?

Comment: what do you means?

Comment: A hyper link to the battery you are using or a model number or something that can be used to check to see if it can supply up to 2 amps of current.

Comment: If you have a 1 amp fuse then I suspect you are NOT taking 2 amps or the fuse will blow.

Comment: @MaulanaMalik. My computations suggest, at 100% efficiency and \$12\:\text{V}\$, that you need 1000 pulses using an inductance of \$8\:\text{mH}\$ and peak current of \$5\:\text{A}\$ to get there in 10 seconds. 10000 pulses using an inductance of \$140\:\mu\text{H}\$ and peak current of \$12\:\text{A}\$ might be an alternative. These are assuming zero losses but give some idea. (These each assume a fixed time period per pulse and allow enough time for worst case off-time.)

Comment: @Andy aka . I've searched, but there are only online store links and on the description just like this:Specs:
Capacity: 5200mAh
Voltage: 3S1P / 3Cell / 11.1
Discharge: 45C Constant 
Weigh : 427 Grams
Dimension : 150x49x27 mm
Balance Plug: JST-XH
Discharge Plug: XT60

Comment: @jonk 21 .how do i make 10000 pulses using an inductance of 140μH and peak current of 12A?

Comment: @MaulanaMalik. May I now suggest that your battery is inadequate to supply the current needed to the circuit to charge the capacitor quickly enough. Another clue is the 1 amp fuse in your circuit - I expect that you are barely able to deliver 0.5 amps and this would extend your charge time to possibly 30 seconds given that I have calculated (roughly) you need certainly more than 0.9 amps and possibly in the region of 1.5 amps to 2 amps. Of course your fuse would blow but that is a simple fix. Try using a more powerful 12 volt supply; one capable of supplying 3 amps.

Comment: @Andy aka. Okay, let me clarify. the problem is the battery / transformer / circuit?

Comment: You haven't clarified anything. Clarify what current is taken from the battery when the capacitor is initially charging. Use a multimeter.

Comment: I mean the main problem is where? on the battery or on my circuit, in your previous answer you said the mosfet is not working maximally.

Comment: my multimeter limit is max 500mA. for the current problem whether my transformer does not help in raising the current. I changed the transformer with secondary 450 turn (0.7mm) and primary 17 turn (1.8mm)

Comment: @MaulanaMalik. **THE BATTERY** - check the current drawn from the battery when the capacitor is being charged. **THE FUSE** - it would blow in about a second if you took 2 amps into the circuit. The MOSFET problem manifests itself because the battery can't supply the current AND its terminal voltage drops AND the MOSFETs don't get driven correctly. Read what I said!!

Comment: sorry i'm not very fluent in english, i just copy your answer on google maps and it's hard to understand what is translated. for the fuse problem I've fixed it. thank you :)

Comment: @MaulanaMalik. I actually think your better bet might be to use an IC. They can pack a lot of goodies into one. But it also means it is boutique and perhaps hard to get hold of. With 12 V available and needing only DC charging plus my own limited experience, I'd go with a discontinuous mode inductor and an MCU I'd code up. To reduce the peak current a bit, I'd go with more inductance. Perhaps a standard of \$2.5\:\text{mH}\$. 2000 pulses for that, and a peak current of \$6.3\:\text{A}\$. Problem will be in diode losses. You need something that can stand off \$300\:\text{V}\$.

Answer (score 1):

I lot has been discussed elsewhere on the web regarding a Baxandall style design. You might look that up for an efficient approach. Personally, I find them harder because of the requirements for probably having to do a custom transformer, which I'm not fully adept at making. So I wouldn't go that route and would pick something easier to do for a hobbyist.

An approach I've used before, but not for this peak voltage, is a discontinuous mode approach. You store energy in the inductor and then release that energy. And there are plenty of inductors available that are designed to work this way, too. Plus, they are not hard to wind or make. At a low frequency like this, I might just use an iron core and file a gap into it for these purposes. But ferrite can work fine here, too.

There are lots of design details that go into the inductor. You have to be sure that the wire can handle the peak current and you want to use an even larger diameter wire than that to reduce the resistance still more to reduce simple resistive losses. But thicker wire also means that the windings require a larger core window. To go with that, there are limitations on the core volume given the energy of each pulse. And using ferrite, with its own limitations, means even bigger still. (Which is probably why I'd go with iron and gap it, instead.)

---

Let's start with power considerations. Those are simple. You need the energy on the capacitor to be \${1\over 2}CV^2\approx 100\:\text{J}\$. You need that done in \$10\:\text{s}\$. So this works out to \$10\:\text{W}\$. That an easy calculation. At a guess, I'd say you'd be lucky if you can do this with an average of \$25\:\text{W}\$ from the power supply. That doesn't say anything about the peak current compliances that are also required, though. So keep that in mind. it's just that I think you might be lucky getting 40% efficiency and you should plan on it being that bad (or worse, perhaps.) This isn't an easy problem if you also include high efficiency into the equation and it is perhaps beyond me to help, then. (I am just a hobbyist and I have no special experiences in this area, besides.)

So that's one detail. And already you know that the average current must be more than \$2\:\text{A}\$ during this period (counting inefficiencies noted above.) You can arrange things so that the difference, between this average and whatever peak requirements are worked out, is handled by some largish capacitor on your power supply. But this is a later consideration. Hold the thought for now.

Now, we know that you need to deliver at least \$10\:\text{W}\$ for a period of \$10\:\text{s}\$ via the inductor itself. (There is no escaping this minimal fact, regardless of the efficiency or inefficiency of the rest of the circuit.) Assuming a fixed frequency (you can do better by varying the OFF period because this changes as the capacitor charges up; but this makes the circuit more complex and I want to avoid that problem), where \$f={1\over t_\text{ON}+t_\text{OFF}}\$, this is a relatively easy equation to write:

$${{{1\over 2} \:I_\text{PK}^2\: L}\over t_\text{ON}+t_\text{OFF}}\ge 10\:\text{W}$$

We still have to solve for the ON and OFF times (and therefore also the frequency), the size of the inductor, and the peak current. And again, keep in mind that the above equation relates *only* to what the inductor itself must be doing to push energy onto the capacitor. It does NOT address itself to losses elsewhere in the circuit, which is a separate subject.

---

Here is the circuit I'm imagining for the purposes of the remaining discussion:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsCpS0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

There is something (an MCU here) driving what amounts to a Darlington switch. There is an inductor attached to this and a free-wheeling diode that is supposedly capable of handling the peak currents as well as the reverse voltage requirements (which are not small.) A Schottky diode might be appropriate for its lower barrier voltage, but it's not easy to find ones capable of standing off that high of a voltage difference. So I'll leave the selection of the diode up to you.

Approximately \$11\:\text{V}\$ will appear across the inductor when the circuit is ON. This will cause a rise in current and, held long enough, will reach our desired \$I_\text{PK}\$ along a nearly linear ramp upwards. This will take time, which I call \$t_\text{ON}\$ above. Once this peak is reached (and this time is known a priori by whatever the design is here), the MCU then turns the circuit OFF and this allows the inductor to self-discharge into the charging capacitor.

Initially, the \$+12\:\text{V}\$ source voltage will just go through the inductor and diode and charge up the capacitor to \$\approx 11.5\:\text{V}\$. Or thereabouts. That will be the starting point for the rest of the charging cycle. This detail helps determine the allowable frequency, as it allows us to make some improved predictions about the worst-case OFF time, \$t_\text{OFF}\$. Another determination of that might also be the so-called time constant that exists between the inductor and the capacitor. However, it turns out that while this matters a little bit at the very early moments, it won't really matter so much over the long haul of charging. It may impact calculations about the total worst-case Webers. But I'm not even going to worry about that for reasons I don't want to waste time on, here.

---

At this point, some design questions start to enter into this. For example, what is the peak current that your batteries can reliably support? You've already mentioned that you are using a \$12\:\text{V}\$ lithium battery that is rated at \$5500\:\text{mAH}\$. Frankly, I don't know what that means. Is it a "3S?" Or a "4S?" Also, these are probably going to be limited to just an amp or two. And frankly? If that's all it is capable of then you aren't going to make it in time. You need something capable of more than a couple of amps to get from A to B in this project. (Because I think we need to plan on more than an average of \$25\:\text{W}\$ from your battery, so that it can support substantial peaks above that average from time to time while operating.)

So now I'm in need of a datasheet for your battery, because the design cannot continue without important details about your battery system and what it is reasonably and rationally capable of delivering.

Comment: the baterai is 2 apms @jonk

Comment: @MaulanaMalik. I don't know what that means, unfortunately. What's the specified range of currents? What's the peak current? What's the internal resistance? Does it vary with load current? Etc.

Comment: there is no link providing data sheet, there is only an online store.. maybe you have a circuit that i can use?

Comment: @MaulanaMalik. There are many possible circuits to choose from. What I provided is only a part of one such. You'd probably want some "feedback" to the MCU so that you could tell when the next cycle can start -- faster charge-up that way. Not shown in the schematic, yet. Then there is software. I don't like some of the pure-analog transformer methods with tickler coils for a variety of reasons. But if you don't want an MCU, those might be a better choice. Given I don't know what an APM is (battery wise) and no datasheet, it's going to be hard to know what the peak current can be.

Comment: my battery currents is 2 Amp

Comment: @MaulanaMalik. That might be enough. So you now know that for the above circuit (which isn't the only way to go) it must be that \$L\cdot f\ge 5\$. If \$L=1\:\text{mH}\$ then \$f\ge 5\:\text{kHz}\$. Etc. But to keep the peak current down and include some off-time, probably \$f\ge 6\:\text{kHz}\$. Taking into account an on-time of about \$180\:\mu\text{s}\$, that' \$2\:\text{mW}\$ (Webers.) Which is HUGE. With ferrites, \$200\:\text{cm}^2\$! Maybe \$20\:\text{cm}^2\$ with iron. So that's a problem. The frequency needs to be a fair bit higher or the cross-section will be impossible.